# Optimized header file conditional inclusion in source c file

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a C source file that conditionally includes two different header files.

```
#ifdef CONDITION
    #define INC_FILE CONDITION
#else
    #define INC_FILE "std_header.h"
#endif

#include INC_FILE
```

I am looking into ways for optimizing the above block and reduce the overall number of statements needed to achieve the above effect. Any pointers ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say, it's the best way

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if `CONDITION` is defined, it is also a header name / source file in quotes, so you could just use

```
#ifndef CONDITION
    #define CONDITION "std_header.h"
#endif
#include CONDITION
```

Or, you can `#include` within the conditional itself:

```
#ifdef CONDITION
    #include CONDITION
#else
    #include "std_header.h"
#endif
```